# .c_str() возвращает какой-то бред

Tags: c++, кодировка, visual-c++, char

День добрый! На C++ считываю данные из файла. В конце имею string, которую мне надо представить в виде const char*, для чего использую .c_str(). Но возвращает он какой-то бред (не только с кириллицей проблемы, а вообще с любым текстом). Файл сохранены в кодировке ANSI. Как можно решить проблему?
Код чтения:

```
ifstream ifs(path);
if (ifs.is_open())
{
    string s;
    s.assign((istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs.rdbuf())), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    cout << s;
    ifs.close();
    return s.c_str();
}
else
    return "";
```

Comment: Сегодня Луна в Юпитере, и телепатические способности резко снижены... Так что прочесть ваш код не получается. А значит, на вопрос, как решить проблему, ответ один: проблему решить можно исключительно самостоятельно.

Comment: @Harry обновил, но тут код, думаю, не сильно более информативен чем то, что я описал

Comment: Код ГОРАЗДО более информативен...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, начнем с того, что вы возвращаете указатель локального объекта, который после вашего `return` уничтожается, и указатель указывает... куда?

Дальше не пояснять?

Comment: Желательно пояснить, ибо в С++ я валенок без подошвы хД

Comment: Судя по `return`, это у вас функция. `s` - локальная переменная в ней. Вы выходите из функции, и все локальные переменные функции уничтожаются. Их больше нет. Что касается `s`, то это вообще локальная переменная блока. И она уничтожается - память, в которой хранилось ее содержимое, освобождается, и может быть перезаписана. А вы возвращаете указатель на эту память. Что приводит к совершенно неопределенному поведению (термин такой) - там может что-то быть записано, может быть перезаписано, словом, может быть абсолютно что угодно.

Comment: Забавно. В C# такого не наблюдал. Ну, уничтожались локальные объекты, но объект-то был передан. А как тогда лучше поступить? У меня задача, казалось бы, простейшая - считать данные из файла в виде const char*, но черт подери...

Comment: Вы были абсолютно правы. Сейчас вынес все из функции и впилил прямо по ходу кода. Объект не уничтожается, все работает как надо. Но, посоветуйте, как можно все же вынести это в функцию?

Comment: Вы передали **не объект**, а указатель. Я не знаю, что вам нужно дальше делать с этой строкой, но почему бы не вернуть именно строку? Все равно вы в нее читаете. А уже там, где нужен указатель - брать его. Потому что иначе нужно выделять динамически память, записывать в нее строку, возвращать указатель. Потом, поработав с ним, не забывать память освободить. Как вариант - сделать строку статической (`static string s`) - такая строка не будет уничтожена, но после следующего вызова этой функции прежний возвращенный указатель станет недействительным; в лучшем случае будет указывать на новые данные

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо большое! Да понимаю уж, что не объект, забываю все, с каким языком я сейчас работаю =) Больно привык к логике C#